# Looking for recommendations on editing Premier Pro on a MacBook Pro

Tags: video-editor, recommendation, mac

My MacBook Pro died today and I am looking for solid advice on a replacement that will be best for working with Adobe Premier Pro 6.

Apple has the new 13" Retina Display and the regular flavor. I have seen a variety of reviews and want to get some solid perspective on which would work best for video editing.

Thanks.

Comment: this may be more suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), actually.

Comment: Although this question would likely be on topic at both SU and ASE, I don't think it's entirely off-topic here.  The OP is clearly looking for tools for video production.  An expert on the subject is likely to have an expert opinion on the hardware to use.  The question may rather be, where is the OP most likely to get a suitable answer... but that would be up to the OP no?

Comment: I think the question is fine for SU, ASE and AVP, but slightly better for ASE than AVP. I suspect the OP would get better answers on ASE than here. Moderation is a community effort here, and I'm happy (and I hope others are too) to hear from anyone who is interested in making sure that AVP (and ASE and SU) is excellent for its stated purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a few reviews of the Retina display machines that suggest that the graphics chip has trouble pushing the display at full resolution. At this point, I think the Retina machines are better suited to the processing of static images for iPad development than for high-res video editing.

Comment: This is helpful. I ended up getting the regular 13" MBP and so far so good. I may need more RAM though and maybe even an SSD. Thanks.